# Web Api token Bearer authorization fails

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, owin

Can some one point me why?

Here is the angularjs method that calls the Api method that requires authorization

```
this.getTasks = function () {
        var request = $http({
            method: "get",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + authService.getToken()
            },
            url: serviceBase + "api/tasks"
        });

        return request;
    };
```

Here is my config

```
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/account/login"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(3),
            Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
        };

        // Token Generation
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthServerOptions);

    }
```

Api method that I call

```
[Authorize]
    public async Task<ICollection<Models.Task>> GetTasks()
    {
        return await repository.GetAll();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a new token and then compare your request Authorization header token. Maybe authService.getToken() return faulty value.